# ERROR while adding meta-oic layer to an Intel Edison image

Tags: git, yocto, intel-edison

I was trying to add `meta-oic` layer to a standard Intel Edison image using the procedure mentioned [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-oic/tree/README).

However after making the required changes in both `bblayers.conf` and `local.conf`, when I use the `bitbake edison-image` command, I am getting the following errors:

```
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

*ERROR1*    
 Nothing RPROVIDES 'nfs-utilsiotivity-resource-samples' (but /home/shivappa/work/edison_brd/edison-src/meta-intel-edison/meta-intel-edison-distro/recipes-core/images/edison-image.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)

NOTE: Runtime target 'nfs-utilsiotivity-resource-samples' is unbuildable, removing...Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['nfs-utilsiotivity-resource-samples']**

*ERROR2*  
Required build target 'edison-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['edison-image', 'nfs-utilsiotivity-resource-samples']
```

I may be committing a very trivial mistake but still I haven't been able to resolve this. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo somewhere: `'nfs-utilsiotivity-resource-samples'`  should be `'nfs-utils iotivity-resource-samples'`.

Most likely reason for a bug like this is using IMAGE_INSTALL_append and missing the space in the beginning, e.g.:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " iotivity-resource-samples"
```

Check you local.conf for a missing space.